# Pylint whitelist mode

Tags: python, pylint

My team is looking into incorporating pylint into our dev process.  In my experience linters are good for very basic checks, but end up producing a lot of false positives and can be more annoying than helpful.  Therefore, I would like to run pylint in a whitelist mode, where all warnings are disabled by default and we gradually add those we are interested in over time.  I did a bit of googling and saw no obvious way to do this.  Is there a way short of manually disabling everything via .pylintrc?

Comment: I think you are looking for [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @letsc I don't see how tox would be related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [pylint docs](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/run.html#command-line-options):

> If you want to enable only some checkers or some message symbols, first use `--disable=all` then `--enable=<symbol>` with  being a comma separated list of checker names and message symbols. See the list of available features for a description of provided checkers with their functionalities.

Comment: Ah, looks like I overlooked the `--disable=all` part.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Disable all the checks, then explicitly enable the ones you want. For example:

```
pylint --score=no --disable=all --enable=unused-argument whatever.py
```